# Aurelia-Cli adding require .scss file

Tags: html, css, requirejs, aurelia

I'm using the Aurelia-Cli to build an aurelia-app.

In the src folder I have app.js and app.html, now I'm adding an app.scss file.

I then require, as the documentation suggests in app.html:

```
<require from="./app.css"></require>
```

Unfortunately this throws an error saying h.load is not a function and unhandled rejection error: Failed loading required CSS file: app.css

I tried require "app.css", "app.scss", sadly, none of them work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I'm assuming this is a very simple problem

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The error suggests that the app.css file does not exist. Make sure you are generating an app.css file from your app.scss file.

Comment: This is telling the problem, not the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

What does your folder structure look like?

When bundling with the cli you need to respect the original, unbundled structure in your `require` tags, i.e., if your `app.scss` is in `src/stylesheets/app.scss` your `require` will look as follows:"

```
<require from="./stylesheets/app.css"></require>
```

Note that I respect the path of the `.scss`but actually require a `.css` file.

Comment: This seems to have changed at some point and now `.scss` is accepted as the correct path and `.css` throws not-found errors.

Comment: This may be webpack only which requires the `scss` extension where CLI bundler accepts `css`.